# Existence of an orthonormal basis on a closed subset of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

In order to prove that if an orthogonal projection $\;P:\mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F\;$ is compact then $\;dimRan(P) \lt \infty\;$, our professor told us:

Since $\;P:\mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F\;$ is an orthogonal projection $\Rightarrow\;\;\;\;Ran(P)\;$ is a closed subset of $\;F\;$ (and so a Hilbert space). Thus, an orthonormal basis exists on $\; Ran(P)\;$.

**My questions:**

1. Why $\;Ran(P)\;$ is a Hilbert space? Don't we need $\;Ran(P)\;$ to be also finite dimensional in order to imply that?
2. Why does an orthonormal basis exist? Even if I assume $\;Ran(P)\;$ is Hilbert space, without the condition of separability, how do I get an orthonormal basis?

I 'm really confused. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $F$ a Hilbert space? If it is, then the answer to the first question follows from that fact that any closed subspace of a complete normed space is complete normed space.

Comment: Any subspace of a Hilbert space is an inner product space, with the same inner product as in the Hilbert space. A closed subspace of a Hilbert space is then complete, and so is a Hilbert space itself.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you, I guess I had misunderstood when a subset of a Hilbert space is Hilbert itself. Could you also help me with the second question?

Comment: Is a subset of a separable Hilbert space separable?

Comment: @mathworker21 hmmm... the answer is yes, but I don't know $\;F\;$ is separable. Should I add this condition?

Comment: Whoops, sorry - I thought you said a countable orthonormal basis. It is a well-known fact that every Hilbert space (not necessarily separable) has an orthonormal basis. This can be proved using Zorn's Lemma

Comment: @mathworker21 oh ok, then.. I 've recently started to study about Hilbert spaces and I'm really new to functional analysis in general.. Thanks for your help!